# M2.4 Exception throwing while executing composer require: Higher matching version 2.3.x of xxx/module-xxxx was found in public repository packagist

Tags: magento2.4, composer

While executing `composer require xxxx/module-xxxx` I'm facing below error on the console. Repository is private at the moment.

```
[Exception]                                                                                                                                    

Higher matching version 2.4.x of xxx/module-xxxx was found in public repository packagist.org  than 2.3.x in private https://repo.magento.com. 

Public package might've been taken over by a malicious entity,

please investigate and update package requirement to match the version from the private repository
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is caused by the 'magento/composer-dependency-version-audit-plugin' module. This module forces composer to prioritize private repositories over public repositories. And seems to also sometimes causes errors while unzipping modules.

The workaround is to just not install this plugin.

Comment: Even though this fixes the issue, this also explicitly circumvents a security feature introduced by Magento. Hence, I would not recommend taking this path.

Comment: Giving up on a genuine and/or valid package is not a workaround. Sometimes by the simple fact of delays on the marketplace on approving new releases affects all other users wanting to install some module or plugin.

Answer (score 28):

When you have a module with a same name at packagist.org and at magento marketplace, and the first is newer than the second, this error will happen. This is caused by magento/composer-dependency-version-audit-plugin module, as explained in the [official docs](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/4410675867917-Composer-plugin-against-Dependency-Confusion-attacks).

This may happen when you don't upload the newest version to the marketplace or they are taking too long to approve your submission.

I found at least 3 ways to workaround the issue, but another user here gave a 4th and better option (**see solution #4**):

### Solution 1: install the latest version from Adobe's Marketplace

Just add `--no-plugins` to your `composer require` command.

For example: `composer require ricardomartins/pagseguro --no-plugins`.

This will ignore the above module execution and it will not check against packagist for newer versions. This way the above message will not be displayed.

### Solution 2: Manually install the latest version

It's not really a solution, but if you really need the latest version from Packagist or Git, you may want to move the module to the `app/code` folder and remove it from composer dependencies (`composer remove package/module`).

### Solution 3: Tell composer Magento is not a canonical repo

This way, if a newer version is available at packagist, it will be installed.

To do this, open `composer.json` file and add `"canonical": false` to Magento's repository, like follows:

```js
  "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/",
            "canonical": false
        }
    ]
```

### Solution 4 : To exclude offending package from the repository.

You can also exclude the `package-vendor/module-name` from the repo.magento.com repository

```js
"repositories": {
    "0": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/",
        "exclude": ["package-vendor/module-name"]
    }
}
```

Thus, running `composer require package-vendor/module-name` will always pick up the latest Packagist release.

(answer provided by [@Julien Loizelet](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/50208/julien-loizelet))

---

Further reading (in Portuguese): I wrote [a help article](https://pagsegurotransparente.zendesk.com/hc/pt-br/articles/4432121990029) about this for the users of my PagSeguro module for Magento facing the same issue.

Comment: 3. doesn't work in this case. Because the offending plugin will never accept a public repository.

Comment: Solution 1 worked very well for me! Thanks!

Comment: As an alternative, you can also exclude the `package-vendor/module-name` from the `repo.magento.com` repository:


    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/",
            "exclude": ["package-vendor/module-name"]
        }
    ]


Thus, running `composer require package-vendor/module-name` will always pick up the latest Packagist release.

Comment: Solution #1 doesn't always work, especially since composer often sees repo.magento.com as the _higher priority_ repo, still preventing you from installing via Composer. Solution #3 is too heavy-handed. The comment here from @JulienLoizelet is really the best answer, as it allows you to selectively choose which modules may be excluded.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. However, I also find it ridiculous that there is no way to remove a package from your Marketplace profile so that this can be avoided.

Comment: Also a strange behavior is the fact that composer1 seems to handle that not like composer2.

Answer (score 2):

If the offending package comes from Packagist, this worked for me

```
"repositories": {
    "packagist.org": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packagist.org",
        "exclude": ["package-vendor/module-name"]
    },
```

Answer (score -3):

I ran into this issue trying to install mageplaza/module-smtp on Ubuntu 20.04. I am not 100% sure why but it turned out composer was installed using apt-get. I removed it and re-installed and the module installed with no issue.

```
sudo apt-get remove composer
```

Then install composer

```
cd ~
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o composer-setup.php
HASH=`curl -sS https://composer.github.io/installer.sig`
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '$HASH') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
sudo php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
alias composer='/usr/local/bin/composer'
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but it's not related to composer installation.